# update contact from account on after update trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

So i've made two custom fields for account and contact. When the account is updated with Total I want each of the contacts to be given an equal amount of money from the Total so if there's two accounts and total is 100 contacts get 50 each.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong here. I'm new to apex and writing test cases in general too so any help appreciated.
The trigger :

```
trigger claimTest on Account (after update) {
for(Account a : Trigger.new){
    if(a.Total__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(a.id).Total__c){
        List<Contact> contactList= [SELECT Share__c FROM CONTACT WHERE Contact.AccountId =: a.id];
        List<Contact> contactList1 = new List<Contact>();
        Decimal price_total = a.Total__c;
        List<AggregateResult>  cnt= [SELECT COUNT(Id) countTask FROM CONTACT WHERE Contact.AccountId =: a.id];  
        Integer tskCount = (Integer)cnt[0].get('countTask'); 

        Decimal divided = price_total/tskCount;

        for(contact c:contactList){
            c.Share__c = divided;
            contactList1.add(c);
        }
        update contactList1;
    }        
}
}
```

The test:

```
@isTest
public class claimTestTest {
static testMethod void TestAccount()
{ 
    Account a = new Account();
    a.Name ='Test Account';
    insert a;

    Contact cont = new Contact();
    cont.FirstName='Test';
    cont.LastName='Test';
    cont.Accountid= a.id;
    insert cont;
    Contact cont2 = new Contact();
    cont2.FirstName='Testing';
    cont2.LastName='Testing';
    cont2.Accountid= a.id;
    insert cont2;

    Account accountToUpdate = new Account();
    accountToUpdate = [SELECT Total__c FROM Account WHERE Name='Test Account'LIMIT 1];
    accountToUpdate.Total__c = 100;
    update accountToUpdate;
    System.debug('Share for ' + cont.Share__c);
    System.assertEquals(50, cont.Share__c);
}   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Even though I (and Himanshu) were able to identify issues in your code (and providing the code was a huge help that a lot of newcomers miss), it generally helps if you include error messages _verbatim_ and describe how the way your code behaves differs from how you expect it to behave. I could make an educated guess that your assertion in your test class was failing, but hearing that explicitly from you is much better than guessing. The less guesswork we have to do, the better/more targeted answers you'll receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For being new to Apex and unit testing, I'd say you did pretty well. There are, of course, issues, but we'll work those out.

The first big thing that I'm seeing with your trigger is that you're querying inside of a loop. Queries inside of loops are bad, and will cause problems (eventually) because you can only use 100 queries (under normal circumstances) per transaction.

The general pattern to use instead is something like...

```
// Declare a collection (usually a list or a set) to hold Ids that we want to use
//   in the query.
List<Id> myRecIds = new List<Id>();

// Iterate over Trigger.new to gather the Ids
for(MyObj__c myRec :Trigger.new){
    myRecIds.add(myRec.someLookup__c);
}

// Perform your query, and then loop over the results.
for(OtherObj__c otherRec :[SELECT Id, someField__c FROM OtherObj__c WHERE Id IN :myRecIds]){
    // Do interesting things in here
}
```

That said, we can do something a little different here. Since `Contact` has a lookup to `Account`, we say that `Account` is the "parent" object and `Contact` is the "child" object. We can perform a parent-child subquery (aka a left outer join). This provides a few benefits, such as having each related `Contact` automatically correlated to its parent `Account` record and being able to determine *how many* `Contacts` an `Account` has without an additional query.

That query looks like this:

```
// The open/close parenthesis enclose the subquery.
// The subquery is placed in the SELECT clause, just like it were a field
// The FROM clause of the subquery uses the child relationship name, which is 
//   'Contacts' in this case
List<Account> acctsWithContactsList = [SELECT Id, Total__c, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new];
```

We can use that to simplify your trigger.

```
trigger claimTest on Account (after update) {
    // DML inside of a loop is also a bad idea, declare a collection to hold the 
    //   Contact records we want to update.
    List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();

    // Using a query to feed a loop like this is called a "soql for loop"
    for(Account a : [SELECT Id, Total__c, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]){
        if(a.Total__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(a.id).Total__c){
            // The subquery gives us a list of the child records.
            // We can access this list using the child relationship name (Contacts).
            // Since it is a list, we can use the size() method to get the number
            //   of related contacts.
            // Directly using subquery results like this only works (reliably) if
            //   you have less than about 200 child records per parent record.
            // If you have more than that, you'll need to use a nested loop.
            Integer numContacts = a.Contacts.size();

            // Now that we know the number of contacts for this account, we can go about
            //   updating Contacts.
            for(Contact cont :a.Contacts){
                // Normally, a check to make sure we won't divide by 0 is a good idea.
                // However, in this case, we won't enter this loop if there are 0 
                //   contacts, so it's safe to ignore the check in this case.
                cont.Share__c = a.Total/numContacts;

                // Add the contact to our list of things to update
                contactsToUpdate.add(cont);
            }
        }
    }

    // Outside of all loops, it's safe to do DML
    update contactsToUpdate;
}
```

As far as your unit test goes, the big thing you were missing was already covered by Himanshu. To assert whether or not your `Contacts` were updated with the correct amount in `Share__c`, you need to re-query the `Contacts`. Other than that, your test has all the important things:

- Creating data inside of the test itself
- Test is not overbroad, focusing on limited input to a small *unit* of code
- Assertion to verify the result

About the only other thing I can say about your test class is that I'd like to see more test methods in it. Right now, you're testing the 'happy path' where your data is well-formed and won't cause any problems. The real world (once you get actual users involved) is more harsh. Writing tests to cover less-than-ideal situations will give you confidence that your code is not only correct, but that it can also stand up to abuse (i.e. your code is 'robust').

Some additional tests that would be good to write:

- What happens when `Account.Total__c` becomes 0 or negative?
- What happens when `Account.Total__c` becomes null?
- What happens if your `Account` has no `Contacts`?
- What happens if your `Account` has only one `Contact`?
- What happens if your `Account` has a couple hundred `Contacts`?
- What happens when `Account.Total__c` can't be evenly divided (e.g. total = 100, 3 `Contacts`)

Each of those would be a different test method.

Answer (score 0):

if you assert without querying again you will not get updated data so your test class should look like this

```
@isTest
public class claimTestTest {
static testMethod void TestAccount()
{ 
    Account a = new Account();
    a.Name ='Test Account';
    insert a;

    Contact cont = new Contact();
    cont.FirstName='Test';
    cont.LastName='Test';
    cont.Accountid= a.id;
    insert cont;
    Contact cont2 = new Contact();
    cont2.FirstName='Testing';
    cont2.LastName='Testing';
    cont2.Accountid= a.id;
    insert cont2;

    Account accountToUpdate = new Account();
    accountToUpdate = [SELECT Total__c FROM Account WHERE Name='Test Account'LIMIT 1];
    accountToUpdate.Total__c = 100;
    update accountToUpdate;
    //query again to get update data after running account trigger.

    List<Contact> lstContact = [select share__c from contact where id=:cont.id]
    System.assertEquals(50, lstContact[0].Share__c);
}   
}
```

You can achieve this functionality using Process builder without writing single line of code.

1. [Create rollup field on Account object (Sum)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249282&type=1)
2. Create process on account object with update.
3. add criteria as any time amount isChanged=True.
4. action update related records.
5. share__c = Total__c/ rollupsummary field name.

Comment: We can't create roll up between Account and Contact.

Comment: @TusharSharma i haved added link in step 1